# Field calculater in Python console from QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, python-toolbox

I have some doubts in syntax of processing.runalg(qgis:fieldcalculator) in python console of QGIS. I want to create a new field in a shapefile and calculate this formula: `[D_PATRICIA]*1000`. (D_PATRICIA= is another field form the table of shapefile that contain values).

I try to do this and retrieved me a shapefile with the new field (p_mm) but without values:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', str4, "p_mm", 1, 6, 6, True, '[D_PATRICIA]*1000', str5)
```

What should be the problem? I think the problem is in the formula parameter. 
Any idea to help me?

My code is:

```
import sys
import processing
import os
indir="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/2014" 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(indir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.nc'): 
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file).replace('\\', '/')
            filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fullname))[0]

            str1="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/2014/"+filename+".tif"
            str2="D:/PATRICIA/IG/ESTACOES METEOROLOGICAS/ESTACOES_SPITFIRE74.shp"
            str3="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/2014/"+filename+".vrt"
            str4="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/2014/"+filename+"_VERAO.shp"
            str5="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/2014/"+filename+"_VERAO1.shp"

            processing.runalg('gdalogr:buildvirtualraster', fullname, 0, True, False, str1)
            processing.runalg('saga:addgridvaluestopoints', str2, str3, 2, str4)
            processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', str4, "p_mm", 1, 6, 6, True, "D_PATRICIA" * 1000, str5)
```

Comment: Instead of `[D_PATRICIA]*1000`, try `"D_PATRICIA" * 1000`.

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work like the other one, the result is the same. Any more options?

Comment: Have you defined `str4` and `str5` in your code somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I defined as:                                      
            
       str4="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/2014/"+filename+"_VERAO.shp"
       str5="D:/PATRICIA/ECMWF/2014/"+filename+"_VERAO1.shp"

Comment: Try using `' "D_PATRICIA" * 1000 '` as your formula (notice the single quotation marks).

Comment: Didn´t work too. I don't know what's the problem. In your opinion the structure of the scrypt is correct? The srypt just have problems in the last line, all another lines are working well.

Comment: It's working now!!! I had the wrong name of field. Thank's. with this code it works: processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', str4, "p_mm", 0, 6, 6, True, ' "D:PATRICIAE" * 1000 ', str5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a wrong name of field so with the corrected field name it works perfectly:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', str4, "p_mm", 0, 6, 6, True, ' "D:PATRICIAE" * 1000 ', str5)
```